# Implementing Protected Routes with UserProvider in NextJS

Tags: typescript, authentication, next.js, supabase

I'm working on a React application where I'm using a `UserProvider` to manage user authentication. The goal is to restrict access to certain routes for non-logged-in users and redirect them to the login page.

Here's a simplified version of my code structure:

My app.tsx file:

```
import '@tamagui/core/reset.css'
import '@tamagui/font-inter/css/400.css'
import '@tamagui/font-inter/css/700.css'
import 'raf/polyfill'

import { NextThemeProvider, useRootTheme } from '@tamagui/next-theme'
import { Provider } from 'app/provider'
import Head from 'next/head'
import React, { useEffect, useMemo } from 'react'
import type { SolitoAppProps } from 'solito'
import Layout from 'components/layout'
import { UserProvider } from '../../../packages/supabase/src/contexts/user'
import { supabaseClient } from '../../../packages/supabase/src/clients/supabase'
import App from 'next/app'
import type { User } from '@supabase/supabase-js'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'


if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  require('../public/tamagui.css')
}

interface MyAppProps extends SolitoAppProps {
  ssrUserData?: User | null
}

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, ssrUserData }: MyAppProps) {

  const router = useRouter();

  const isUserLoggedIn = ssrUserData !== null;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isUserLoggedIn) {
      router.push('/login'); // Hier musst du den richtigen Pfad zur Login-Seite angeben
    }
  }, [isUserLoggedIn]);

  const contents = useMemo(() => {
    return (
      // @ts-ignore
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    )
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [pageProps])
  
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Ensemble</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Tamagui, Solito, Expo & Next.js" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <ThemeProvider>
          {contents}
      </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  )
}

function ThemeProvider({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useRootTheme()

  return (
    <NextThemeProvider
      onChangeTheme={(next) => {
        setTheme(next as any)
      }}
    >
      <Provider disableRootThemeClass defaultTheme={theme}>
        <Layout>
          {children}
        </Layout>
      </Provider>
    </NextThemeProvider>
  )
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext: any) => {
  // calls page's `getInitialProps` and fills `appProps.pageProps`
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);

  const { data: userData, token  } = await supabaseClient
    .auth
    .api
    .getUserByCookie(appContext.ctx.req)

  return { 
    ...appProps, 
    ssrUserData: userData ?? null,
  }
}

export default MyApp
```

I have a UserProvider Component:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useUser } from '@supabase/supabase-auth-helpers/react';
import { User } from '@supabase/supabase-js';

type UserContextProps = { user?: User | null };

export const UserContext = createContext<UserContextProps | null>(null);

export const UserProvider = ({ ssrUserData, children }: any) => {
  const [ ssrUser, setSsrUser ] = useState<User | null>(ssrUserData);
  const { user: supabaseAuthUser } = useUser(); // supabase-auth-helpers
  
  // use user data as fallback
  const user = supabaseAuthUser || ssrUser || null

  // once auth-helpers user is available, remove  user data
  useEffect(() => { 
    if(ssrUser && supabaseAuthUser) setSsrUser(null) 
  }, [supabaseAuthUser]);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ user }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

And a Component to handle the login:

```
import { handleAuth } from "@supabase/supabase-auth-helpers/nextjs"
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next"

export default function AuthHandler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  // fix the 'No cookies found!' console error
  // breaks realtime
  //
  // if(req.headers.cookie || req.query.supabase[0] === 'callback') {
  //   handleAuth()(req, res)
  // } else {
  //   res.status(200).json({})
  // } 
  
  handleAuth()(req, res)
}
```

I have a `UserProvider` that handles user authentication. The `ssrUserData` prop is used to determine whether a user is logged in.

The problem I'm facing is that the page initially loads, and then the user is redirected to the login page if they are not logged in. Ideally, I want to prevent the page from loading at all for non-logged-in users and immediately redirect them to the login page.

How can I implement protected routes in my application using the `UserProvider` to achieve this behavior? Any suggestions or corrections to my code would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

I tried to put the router into the UserProvider but I don´t think that is the best solution.